# How use if-else or condition to input elements of matrix B(pu)?

Tags: python, matrix

import numpy as np

rows_a = int(input("Input number of rows A : " ))

column_c = int(input("Input number of column C: "))

print(" Input elements  of matrix Bb:")

Bb= [[int(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]
print("Matrix Bb=: ")
for n in Bb:
print(n)

print("Input elements  of matrix Ba:")

Ba= [[int(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]
print("Matrix Ba=: ")
for m in Ba:
print(m)

print("Matrix B(pu)")
for each p in range(column_c) and u in range(rows_a)
if i=p in range(column_c)] and j=u in range(rows_a)
B(pu)[i][j]= [[ int(input((Ba)[i][j]))]
else:
B(pu)[i][j]= [[ int(input((Bb)[i][j]))]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

rows_a = int(input("Input number of rows A : " ))

column_c = int(input("Input number of column C: "))

print(" Input elements of matrix Bb:")

Bb= [[int(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)] print("Matrix Bb=: ") for n in Bb: print(n)

print("Input elements of matrix Ba:")

Ba= [[int(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)] print("Matrix Ba=: ") for m in Ba: print(m)

print("Matrix B(pu)") 
for each p in range(column_c) and u in range(rows_a) 
if i=p in range(column_c)] and j=u in range(rows_a) 
B(pu)[i][j]= [[ int(input((Ba)[i][j]))] 

else: B(pu)[i][j]= [[ int(input((Bb)[i][j]))]
```

???????????

Comment: Proper indentation and formatting is necessary